# Laravel Table with edit modal in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to make a table with a edit button in each row. edit button will render a modal popup with the loaded data of the row.

here is my blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">       
    @foreach($employee_education as $employee_education)
        <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
            <div class="card-header bg-white">
                <h5 class="card-title m-0">
                    {{ $employee_education->degree_title }}
                </h5>
                <a 
                    href="#" 
                    data-toggle="modal" 
                    id="education_edit_link" 
                    data-target="#education_edit_modal" 
                    class="btn  btn-primary btn-xs" 
                    style="float:right;color:white!important;"
                >
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body bg-light">
                <table class="table table-hover table-sm  table-borderless">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Degree Title</th>
                            <td>{{$employee_education->degree_title}}   </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Institute</th>
                            <td>{{$employee_education->institute}}  </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Address </th>
                            <td>{{$employee_education->address}}    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div 
            class="modal fade" 
            id="education_edit_modal" 
            tabindex="-1" 
            role="dialog" 
            aria-labelledby="connection_detailsLabel" 
            aria-hidden="true"
        >
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table table-hover table-sm  table-borderless">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Degree Title</th>
                                        <td>{{$employee_education->degree_title}}   </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Institute</th>
                                        <td>{{$employee_education->institute}}  </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Address </th>
                                        <td>{{$employee_education->address}}    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_update" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal End -->    
@endforeach
```

But the modal only showing the first row data everytime.How can I get data of clicked row's data loaded in my modal

Comment: Don't use the same `id` attributes in a loop. `id`s need to be unique in a document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because all your modals have the same id.

You can easily add the ids of your employee_education as the id of the modal:

1. You need to adapt your toggle link, append employee_education->id to the id of the :

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" id="education_edit_link" 
data-target="#education_edit_modal{{$employee_education->id}}"...
```

2. Append the same id to your modals id

```
<div class="modal fade" id="education_edit_modal{{$employee_education->id}}" 
        ... >
```

Please Note:
You are using `$employee_education as $employee_education` in your foreach loop. You might need to rename the variable as they are named the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Causes**

If you check the `DOM` you will find that you have multiple modals as it is rendering one for each time it loops through your `$employee_education` collection.

Each of these modals will have the same `id` attribute as you are not changing this within the loop (i.e. each will have an id of `education_edit_modal`).

As an `id` should be unique it will stop looking after the first time it finds an element with that `id`. This is why it always has the content from the first object in your loop.

---

**Solutions**

1. Try rendering just a single modal outside of your loop and pass it data using `data` attributes. This is more efficient and doesn't require you to have some sort of dynamic id generation.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: Good catch about the `data` attributes, I didn't think about that at first.